# Updating records in jqgrid is not working

Tags: jquery, html, jqgrid

I am working on a jqgrid where i need to update the records inline, by clicking the edit button, make some changes and then on clicking the save button. I am getting an error window while updating the records.

html:

```
 <table id="grid"></table>
 <div id="pager"></div>
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/g27gL/) is my fiddle,

Can someone suggest what needs to be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

refer this working inline edit [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aditib/CzVVK/)

```
 $("#grid").jqGrid({
 data: mydata,
 datatype: "local",
 colNames: ["Name", "Country", "Continent"],
 colModel: [{
    name: 'name',
    index: 'name',
    editable: true,
 }, {
    name: 'country',
    index: 'country',
    editable: true,
 }, {
    name: 'continent',
    index: 'continent',
    editable: true,
 }],
 pager: '#pager',
 'cellEdit': true,
 'cellsubmit' : 'clientArray',
 editurl: 'clientArray'
});
```